# Magento, default layout for the custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I want to add a block in left column of only my module, not whole website.

If I place it in `<default>` tag it will be shown in whole website, but I want to do something like `<mymodule_default>`, is it possible ?

I know I can place my block in every `layout_handler` like

```
 <mymodule_controllername_actionname>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="mymodule/block" name="left_navigation" before="-" template="mymodule/left-nav.phtml" />
    </reference>
 </mymodule_controllername_actionname>
```

but this is not what I want, I want to do it as

```
 <mymodule_default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="mymodule/block" name="left_navigation" before="-" template="mymodule/left-nav.phtml" />
    </reference>
 </mymodule_default>
```

Or it is not preferable ??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add layout update handle in each controller

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    $this
        ->getLayout()
        ->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('mymodule_default');
}
```

Or with instruction `<update handle="mymodule_default"/>` in all `<mymodule_controllername_actionname>` handles

Example:

```
<mymodule_controllername_actionname>
    <update handle="mymodule_default"/>
    ...
<mymodule_controllername_actionname>
```